# Obtain Thread Info from tls callback

Tags: c++

So I have a tls callback implemented in a separate dll and I want to retrieve the thread information on thread attach like the entry point,
parameters etc

```
void NTAPI on_tls_callback(LPVOID dll, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    if (reason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH)
    {
        //obtain thread info
    }           
}



#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__xl_b")
#pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLB")
EXTERN_C

PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK _xl_b = on_tls_callback;
#pragma data_seg()
```

I read here that it's possible
[How can DLL injection be detected?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/how-can-dll-injection-be-detected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a bit of further research I found a way here
[Thread EntryPoint in TLS callback as AntiDebug technique](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/thread-entrypoint-in-tls-callback-as-antidebug-technique)

```
typedef NTSTATUS
(NTAPI*NtQueryInformationThread_t)(
IN HANDLE ThreadHandle,
IN THREADINFOCLASS ThreadInformationClass,
OUT PVOID ThreadInformation,
IN ULONG ThreadInformationLength,
OUT PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
);

void NTAPI on_tls_callback(LPVOID dll, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{

    if (reason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH)
    {
        DWORD startAddress = 0;
        NtQueryInformationThread_t pNtQueryInformationThread = 
 reinterpret_cast<NtQueryInformationThread_t>(GetProcAddress(
            GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationThread"));
        pNtQueryInformationThread(GetCurrentThread(), THREADINFOCLASS(9), 
 &startAddress, sizeof(startAddress), nullptr);

        }           
}



#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__xl_b")
#pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLB")
EXTERN_C

PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK _xl_b = on_tls_callback;
#pragma data_seg()
```